# Automate the add appointment event in Outlook through java code

Tags: java, .net, windows, outlook

Is it possible to automate the appointment adding process of outlook through java code?

Is there any libraries, which can be used for this kind of operations, available?

Please give a help towards the problem..

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got a similar kind of process, which sends email from Outlook, here http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseMicrosoftIntegration/article.html

It can be used as a reference to do automation on Outlook using java code